# Liferay portlet development on JBoss AS 6

Tags: jboss, liferay, jboss6.x

I am trying to create a new Portlet project (basically a portlet for Liferay) in Eclipse (Helios with Liferay SDK installed). I use JBoss AS 6.10.final and Liferay 6.05.

The problem is that everytime I try to create new portlet, it asks me for Runtime Enviroment. I want this enviroment to be JBoss AS, but Eclipse only suggests different Tomcat distributions. I dont have Tomcat bundle installed and I am not going to since it will run on JBoss AS.

Liferay is already installed on JBoss and running (when I start the JBoss AS, I can access the liferay portal page - it has all jars and wars on correct places in AS).

I havent found any tutorial how to make this work. Could someone perhaps provide some step by step guide or direct me to any existing one? Thank you!

PS: I hope that my question is not too confusing, if so, I will try to edit it and make myself clearer...

Comment: If I may suggest something, JBOSS and tomcat require WAR file to be deployed, so the portlet WARs that will be created will be server agnostic so you may develop it in tomcat and then for the final testing you can deploy the WAR file on JBOSS. I hope you won't be using any native jboss library in your code, if that is the case then you might set-up the jboss libraries in the class path of your project in addition to the tomcat runtime if you want to use the Liferay IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured it out:

I changed the **build.username.properties** file

```
app.server.portal.dir=c:\\Programs\\jboss-6.1.0.Final-ESB-4.12\\server\\default\\deploy\\liferay-portal-6.0.5.war
app.server.lib.global.dir=c:\\Programs\\jboss-6.1.0.Final-ESB-4.12\\common\\lib
app.server.deploy.dir=c:\\Programs\\jboss-6.1.0.Final-ESB-4.12\\server\\default\\deploy
app.server.type=jboss
app.server.dir=c:\\Programs\\jboss-6.1.0.Final-ESB-4.12
```

so it points to the directory with liferay war files. Then I had to check in Eclipse that I do not want this file to be overwritten again and it works just fine. I can deploy all projects to JBoss using Liferay SDK!